# spy++: Help interpreting messages on spy++

Tags: python, visual-studio, winapi, spy++

I was using spy++ to log the keystrokes being sent to a game to simulate it myself using SendMessage() on Python. I have looked at the msdn documentation for `WM_KEYUP` and `WM_KEYDOWN`, so I was looking to interpret the lParam values using Spy++.

[image: Spy++ logs for messages being sent]

Can someone help me interpret these messages on spy++? I don't know what frepeat, crepeat and the fup values are. I tried Googling them, but couldn't find any source explaining what these parameters are.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown

Comment: What you are trying to do is not going to work: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: @manuell Like I said I already checked the msdn documentation for ```WM_KEYDOWN``` and ```WM_KEYUP``` and the first 16 bits are a repeat count. But which one is it? frepeat or crepeat?And what is fup? It would be more helpful if you could answer these questions.

Comment: Try to select the "Raw Message Parameters" check box in the "Output" tab in the "Message Options" Dialog box. You may be able to "retro document" the whole thing. (and you then should use `SendInput`...)

Comment: @RameshRaghavan Does the answer below help to you? Please feel free to mark it as answer to help people with the same questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spy++ logs the attributes of [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) in the same order that they are documented. Thus, `cRepeat` is the "repeat count", `fRepeat` is the "previous key state", and `fUp` is the "transition state".